# How to convert a byte array in Java to Oracle databse raw type?

Tags: java, oracle, arrays, converters, draw

As the oracle database column type is raw, so everything is binary right?

like "7D798B72" but i want to search by this column, i know the `byte[]` b of my searching column.

```
select * from table where column=b
```

How can i search by the `byte[] b`?

I tried the following to convert raw to varchar:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(column) FROM table;
```

However, I think it is incorrect as I get garbled words like this "`}y?r`"

Comment: If you pass in a `byte[]` array, then Oracle should be able to do the comparison automatically, assuming that the column is a binary string type.

Comment: hi,@TimBiegeleisen thanks for answer timely.  but how can i search it in pl/sql?

Comment: i thinks oracle can do the comparison automatically from byte[] to raw/